# Scala: Call a pure function that has another pure function as parameter (HOF) in a one-liner

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, higher-order-functions

This is my code:

```
  def f1(x: Int, y: Int, f2: Int => Int): Int = {
    x + y
  }
  def f2(z: Int): Int = {
    z*z
  }
```

I want to call the functions in a one-liner, but haven't been successfull. I have tried the following:

```
f1(1,2, f2(3))

val f2Res = f2(3)
f1(1, 2, f2Res)
```

I'm expecting the following result: *f1(1, 2, f2(3) = 3 + 9 = 12*, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Int => Int
    f1(1,2, f2(3))
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong and what I am not understanding.

Comment: `f2(3)` is not a **function** is a value, try with just `f2` and please take a look at any introduction tutorial of the language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have gone through much materials, could you maybe pin-point me to the specific subject I should look more into? Is it HOF or something else?

Comment: @binaryglot Consider Scala Exercises  [Higher Order Functions](https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/higher_order_functions). The key is to understand the difference between the concept of a function **application** `f(42)`  which produces a value, and the concept of function as a **value** itself `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually pretty clear: The third parameter of `f1` is supposed to be a *function*, but you are passing in a *number*. `f2(3)` is not a *function*, it is the *number* `9`.

Instead of `f2(3)`, you need to pass in a *function*. (Note: `f1` and `f2` are *methods* not *functions*, but you can easily convert a method to a function using η-expansion.)

It would look something like this:

```scala
f1(1, 2, f2 _)
//=> 3: Int
```

However, note that the result is `3` and not `12`, since `f1` is completely ignoring its third argument. It doesn't actually do anything with `f2`, it simply returns `x + y` and throws away the third argument.

If you want to actually do something with the function you are passing as the third argument, you need to call it.